# When does a Markov process induce a C0-semigroup?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(X_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ be a time homogenous Markov process with values in a polish space E and transition kernels $(P_{t})_{t \geq 0}$. Let $B(E,\mathbb{R})$ be the bounded and measureable maps from $E$ to $\mathbb{R.}$ Under which conditions is $(\bar{P}_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ a C0-semigroup where $\bar{P}_{t}:B(E,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow B(E,\mathbb{R}), \bar{P}_{t}f(x)= \int_{E}f(y)P_{t}(x,dy)$?

Comment: Feller process?

Comment: Thanks. Is a every rightcontinuous strong markov process a Feller process?